# Unable to see Tables & Views folder within object explorer ssms - synapse dedicated pool

Tags: azure-synapse, user-permissions

I have granted users access to db_datareader on a particular database on a dedicated SQL pool but the user is unable to see the folders (Tables & Views) in ssms object explorer.
NOTE: The user is able to query the tables when he knows the name.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZpTb.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Check the following conditions:**

- Check the proper roles are assigned or not.
- Refresh in object explorer because SSMS does not do it automatically we need to do it mannually.
- Another approach would be to detach and rejoin SSMS with the server.
- The server forces you to connect to a single database if you're using several users to connect to it.

Refer - [SQL Authentication in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/sql-authentication?tabs=provisioned)

Comment: Administrator users can see tables & views dropdown, but general log users cannot see these folders under a database. I even tried to add them to db_owner role as well as granted them view definition but it still doesn't show up

Comment: Try to provide the user access to View Definition by `Right click on the database name >> Properties >> Permissions >> select the user >> Click on "View Definition" checkbox.`

Comment: I have already tried this, even after it isn't showing tables & views. Are there any other permissions to be granted to the user apart from the below - GRANT ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS TO newuser;
GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::Analytics TO newuser;